# Aumentar exposición de un servicio

Tags: sql

Estoy pensando en realizar un sistema de pago y que a través del mismo existan 3 planes (Básico, Destacado y superdestacado). Ya tengo las pasarelas de pago, diseñe la lógica del plan de suscripción y me falta como destacar a estas publicaciones.

Básicamente tengo la idea de armar las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para mostrar las publicaciones tengo un buscador y retorna todo lo encontrado en base a lo buscado:

```
$publicaciones = Publication::search($request->get('termino'))->get();
```

Me pueden iluminar como puedo mostrar primero las publicaciones de pago y después las que no tienen exposición?

Comment: Considero que ayudaría expongas mejor tu duda, al menos yo no la termino de entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de lograrlo es utilizando `ORDER BY` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
      p.nombre AS nombre
FROM publicaciones p
ORDER BY p.publi_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT publi_id FROM suscripciones)
```

Básicamente el criterio de ordenación se guiará de si la publicacion está, o no, en la tabla de suscripciones, en este caso, primero mostrará las que sí están.

Con este `subquery` obtienes los id de las publicaciones que tienen suscripcion (de pago).

```
SELECT DISTINCT publi_id FROM suscripciones
```

[Aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dad8a/24) tienes un ejemplo funcional.

---

Dado que estás usando `Eloquent`, puedes ayudarte de [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderbyraw). No has mostrado la manera en la que haces la consulta pero aquí un ejemplo:

```
Publicacion::orderByRaw("NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT publi_id FROM suscripciones)")
     ->get();
```

Comment: Hola @L.FLor valoro inmensamente terrible explicación, estoy tratando de entender como puedo hacer en mi caso, es mucho pedir si te muestro lo que yo tengo y me das una idea de como puedo aplicarlo en mi caso?

Comment: Adelante, lo importante es encontrar respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Gracias!!! desconozco como podría iniciar un chat, como te puedo mostrar ?

Comment: Puedes escribir [aqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116281/aumentar-exposicion-de-un-servicio)